Can't execute tests after upgrading WebdriverIO 8.32.x to 9.2.x
We have been using WebdriverIO 8.32.3 to test apps for a long time and it has been very stable. We have tried to upgrade to WebdriverIO 9.2.1, but now it's throwing an error.
When I try to execute:
npm run TestX
I get the following error (it was working fine with version 8:32.x):
node:internal/modules/run_main:125
    triggerUncaughtException(
    ^
Error: tsx must be loaded with --import instead of --loader
The --loader flag was deprecated in Node v20.6.0 and v18.19.0
    at initialize (file:///C:/Projects/TestAutomation.UITests.DesignQualityAndReleaseGovernance/node_modules/tsx/dist/esm/index.mjs:1:919)
    at Hooks.addCustomLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:181:24)
    at Hooks.register (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:155:16)
    at async initializeHooks (node:internal/modules/esm/utils:317:5)
    at async customizedModuleWorker (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:109:13)

We are using NodeJS v22.1.0.
How can I resolve this?

Update your tsx to latest and in your package.json file, update the script for TestX, the recomeneded solution is to run tsx directly: tsx ./file.ts
ref: https://github.com/redwoodjs/redwood/pull/9653
and tsx documentation: https://tsx.is/
ref. for deprecation: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/51048
If for some reason you can't do that downgrade your node version.
// package.json
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsx ./file.ts"
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
